# Column Offset and centering not working in Small Screens (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list which needs to be centered in all screen sizes. I have the following code for it -

```
<div class="container container-fluid.body-content">
   <div class="row">
      <h2 style="text-align:center;">Select your Campus</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 btn-group-vertical" style="background-color:#EAEBED;padding:2%;" id="dispcolleges" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="storeValue('4847453903781888','National Institute of Technology Karnataka')">National Institute of Technology Karnataka</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="storeValue('5743114304094208','Test')">Test</button></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

It is centered with offset in large and medium screens, but not on small screens. How do I fix this?

Full code can be found [here](http://1drv.ms/1QDJPFc)

Comment: better give us a fiddle rather than full code mate! :)

Comment: Because you have zero offset for small screens with full 12 columns -- `col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0`?? More info here -- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: @Abhitalks even without col-sm-offset-0 , the output doesnt change. Still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="container container-fluid.body-content">
  <div class="row">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;">Select your Campus</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6 btn-group-vertical col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color:#EAEBED;padding:2%;" id="dispcolleges" role="group" aria-label="..."><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="storeValue('4847453903781888','National Institute of Technology Karnataka')">National Institute of Technology Karnataka</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="storeValue('5743114304094208','Test')">Test</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `display: inline-block;` of class `btn-group-vertical`

Solution: Add `display: inherit;` for your `<div>`. Try this:

```
    <div class="container container-fluid.body-content">
      <div class="row">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">Select your Campus</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 btn-group-vertical" style="background-color:#EAEBED;padding:2%;display: inherit;" id="dispcolleges" role="group" aria-label="..."><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="storeValue('4847453903781888','National Institute of Technology Karnataka')">National Institute of Technology Karnataka</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="storeValue('5743114304094208','Test')">Test</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```